# How to make a map in prolog from function name to function term

Tags: dictionary, prolog

I have my database like this in Prolog

```
abc1(1,2,3).
abc2(2,5,3).
abc3(3,2,7).
abc4(2,5,7).
abc5(5,2,3).
abc6(6,2,9).
abc7(7,4,3).
```

Now for a input list like

```
L=[abc1,abc2,abc3]
f(L,X) gives
```

X a list of list of X,Y,Z for abc1(X,Y,Z) ,similarly for abc2 and abc3.
I'm not able to do this , basically i want for given abci the corresponding abci(X,Y,Z).

Answer (score 0):

First you can write a predicate get_args/2 :

```
get_args(Name, [A,B,C]) :-
    call(Name, A, B, C).
```

Now your function f can be writteln :

```
f(L, X) :-
    maplist(get_args, L, X).
```